# explicit template instantiation gives compile error on XLC, but works on other compilers

Tags: c++, implementation, c++03, xlc

The following code is a simplified minimal version of a feature I am trying to implement for a client requirement.

It fails to compile on IBM's XLC compiler (version 9 and 11, both) with the error `A non-type template parameter cannot have type "int X::*".`. However, I have tried the same code with g++ 4.7.2, clang++ 3.2 and Intel-13.0, and they compile it successfully.

I am curious to know if XLC is the only sane voice here, or are the other compilers correct?

```
struct X {
    X() : y(123) {}
    int y;
};

struct XFoo {
   typedef int X::* Type;
};

template <typename Name, typename Name::Type value>
struct Bar {
    typename Name::Type getValue(Name) {
        return value;
    }
};

template class Bar<XFoo, &X::y>;    // xlc error here, works fine on others

int main() {}
```

I read through the C++ 2003 standard chapter on templates several times, and could not conclusively find something which prohibits using `<type> <class>::*` as a non-template type. I have already searched through SO and search engines for an explanation, but have not come across any authoritative source which helps me decide.

I understand that this may not be a good coding practice, but this is required for the client code since their requirement is somewhat unique. I have also tried out various other alternatives but it does not work for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

§ 14.1/4 of the C++03 Standard **allows** having pointers to member as a template parameter:

> A **non-type** template-parameter shall have one of the following (optionally cv-qualified) types:
>
> - integral or enumeration type,
> - pointer to object or pointer to function,
> - reference to object or reference to function,
> - **pointer to member**.

Correspondingly, per § 14.3.2/1:

> A template-argument for a **non-type**, non-template template-parameter shall be **one of**:
>
> - an integral constant-expression of integral or enumeration type; or
> - the name of a non-type template-parameter; or
> - the address of an object or function with external linkage, including function templates and function template-ids but excluding non-static class members, expressed as & id-expression where the & is optional if the name refers to a function or array, or if the corresponding template-parameter is a reference; or
> - **a pointer to member expressed as described in 5.3.1**.

Thus, non-type template parameters *can* be pointers to member. There are some limitations which apply to template specialization, but they don't seem to apply in this case.

Comment: Thanks. Be aware though that explicit _instantiation_ is not the same as explicit _specialization_. I need to read the standard more carefully once again.

Comment: @Deidara-senpai: You're right actually, I don't know why I was thinking of a specialization while reading your code, when that's actually an explicit instantiation (still covered by the term "specialization" I believe, but... well nevermind)

Comment: Happens a lot of times with standardese. No worries. :)

Answer (score 1):

Pointer-to-member template parameters are explicitly allowed, XLC should be served a bug report.